# Unable to load image from sdcard to canvas

Tags: android, canvas, android-bitmap

How can I load an image from sdcard to canvas. I tried this code and it is not working.

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    if (selectedImage == null) {
        Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "selected image uri is null");
        return;
    }

    String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
    if(cursor==null){
        Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "image cursor is null");
        return;
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));
    cursor.close();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
    Bitmap bitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getHeight(),bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getConfig());
    mCanvas.setBitmap(bitmap2);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    mCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,0,0,p);
```

What is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know where this `Uri` is coming from. However:

- Get rid of all the `MediaStore` stuff
- Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`
- Use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` to decode from that stream

Also:

- Make sure that you request `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, including handling runtime permissions
- Eventually, move the `openInputStream()` and `decodeStream()` work to a background thread
- Consider switching to [an image-loading library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46)

Comment: @CommonsWareI have changed the code as you said and moved the image loading into async task. I can see the loaded bitmap to the canvas in the debugger. but it is not displaying on the screen

Comment: @sony: You may want to temporarily load it into an `ImageView`, until you are certain that you have the `Bitmap` loaded properly. You might also consider passing `null` instead of a `new Paint()`.

Comment: i tried loading the image into an imageview and it is working but i don't know why it is not showing the canvas with the image

Comment: the width and height of `mBitmap` of canvas returns -1